# How to implement an if-statement in an order form

Tags: javascript, forms, if-statement, null

I'm building a simple order form with some calculations with number & hidden fields (for email and autoresponder).

When the user input field is not '0' i want it to calculate the delivery cost in the total price. In the script below the Delivery cost always returns '0' even when the user field is not '0'.

If I change the value to a certain value it always returns that value even when the user field is '0'. So the IF is wrong somehow.

```js
/* Get the values from the user*/
function getAantal() {
    var AantalBoek = document.getElementById('AantalBoek').value;
    var AantalCD = document.getElementById('AantalCD').value;
    var AantalSoundtrack = document.getElementById('AantalSoundtrack').value;

    /* Product variables*/
    var PrijsBoek = document.getElementById('PrijsBoek').value;
    var PrijsCD = document.getElementById('PrijsCD').value;
    var PrijsSoundtrack = document.getElementById('PrijsSoundtrack').value;

    /* Delivery variables, Soundtrack does not have delivery*/
    /* in my logic the IF says: if user fills in 0 for AantalBoek, 
    then VerzendingBoek is 0 instead of 7. But it always returns 0, even if AantalBoek is 1*/
    var VerzendingBoek = document.getElementById('VerzendingBoek').value;
    if (AantalBoek !== null && AantalBoek !== '') {
        VerzendingBoek = 0;
    }

    var VerzendingCD = document.getElementById('VerzendingCD').value;
    if (AantalCD !== null && AantalCD !== '') {
        VerzendingCD = 0;
    }

    /* Calculation of the Product total*/
    var SubTotaalBoek = PrijsBoek * AantalBoek;
    var SubTotaalCD = PrijsCD * AantalCD;
    var SubTotaalSoundtrack = PrijsSoundtrack * AantalSoundtrack;

    /* Calculation of the Delivery total*/
    var TotaalVerzending = +VerzendingBoek + +VerzendingCD;

    /* Calculation of the Final total*/
    var Totaal = +SubTotaalBoek + +SubTotaalCD + +SubTotaalSoundtrack + +TotaalVerzending;

    document.getElementById('Verzending').value = TotaalVerzending;
    document.getElementById('TotaalPrijs').value = Totaal;
}
```

```html
<!-- user defines values here: -->
<input type="number" id="AantalBoek" required="" onchange="getAantal()">
<input type="number" id="AantalCD" required="" onchange="getAantal()">
<input type="number" id="AantalSoundtrack" required="" onchange="getAantal()">

<!--  set values for the products: -->
<input type="hidden" id="PrijsBoek" name="PrijsBoek" value="15">
<input type="hidden" id="PrijsCD" name="PrijsCD" value="4">
<input type="hidden" id="PrijsSoundtrack" name="PrijsSoundtrack" value="2">

<!-- set values for the delivery cost: -->
<input type="hidden" id="VerzendingBoek" name="VerzendingBoek" value="7">
<input type="hidden" id="VerzendingCD" name="VerzendingCD" value="2">

<!-- totals are shown here (only for autorespond) -->
<input type="hidden" id="Verzending" name="Verzending">
<input type="hidden" id="TotaalPrijs" name="TotaalPrijs">
```

Comment: What's the problem with all these small snippets?

Comment: thanks for your reply. The if-statements in the second and third snippet are somehow not correct. When the user value is 0 the delivery cost is still added to the total

Comment: Please add all information, incouding your debugging attempts, to the question

Comment: I just changed the question. Hope this is more clear for you. As I said I'm new here so any feedback to improve my writings is welcome.

Comment: Thanks for editing. Please also share your debugging attempt. On SO, it's more likely that somebody will help you if you show that you've already tried something on your own. Especially if you state that parts are "somehow not correct", you should explain **why** and what you've tried to fix these problems

Comment: Hi Nico, because I was building the script on the go I was not keeping record of the things that didn't work. So I studied the IF statement again and found the solution. Thanks for pushing me ;-) as I understand now this forum is not for getting people to solve things for you. But at the time of posting I was kinda desperate. ciao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i've started over, looking again at the if-statement and i found a syntax error, changed the condition and added an else statement.

The corrected script is this:

```
function getAantal(){
var AantalBoek = document.getElementById('AantalBoek').value;
var AantalCD = document.getElementById('AantalCD').value;
var AantalSoundtrack = document.getElementById('AantalSoundtrack').value;

var PrijsBoek = document.getElementById('PrijsBoek').value;
var PrijsCD = document.getElementById('PrijsCD').value;
var PrijsSoundtrack = document.getElementById('PrijsSoundtrack').value;

var VerzendingBoek = document.getElementById('VerzendingBoek').value; 
/* Here I changed the condition: IF the user value is 0 then the delivery cost is 0, 
ELSE use the value that was already defined:*/
if(AantalBoek == 0) { VerzendingBoek = 0;
} else {VerzendingBoek = document.getElementById('VerzendingBoek').value;
}
var VerzendingCD = document.getElementById('VerzendingCD').value;
if(AantalCD == 0) { VerzendingCD = 0;
} else {VerzendingCD = document.getElementById('VerzendingCD').value;
}
/*for the second condition i corrected the syntax error !== to !=, 
IF delivery cost for Boek is not 0, then delivery cost for CD is 0*/
if (VerzendingBoek != 0) { VerzendingCD = 0;
}

var SubTotaalBoek = PrijsBoek * AantalBoek;
var SubTotaalCD = PrijsCD * AantalCD;
var SubTotaalSoundtrack = PrijsSoundtrack * AantalSoundtrack;

var TotaalVerzending = +VerzendingBoek + +VerzendingCD;

var Totaal = +SubTotaalBoek + +SubTotaalCD + +SubTotaalSoundtrack + +TotaalVerzending;

document.getElementById('Verzending').value=TotaalVerzending;
document.getElementById('TotaalPrijs').value=Totaal;
}
```